# Ubuntu 20.4 suspends when switching with KVM-switch

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, suspend, kvm-switch

Recently, my HP ProBook 640 was upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 coming from 18.04..

I use a hardware DisplayPort/USB KVM Switch (KVM meaning here: keyboard, video, mouse) to switch between computers, as the same monitor/peripherals are shared among several computers.

Since the upgrade to 20.04, the notebook dives immediately into suspension mode when switching away from it to another machine. This was not the case with 18.04.
I suspect that 20.04 now interprets this monitor/keyboard/mouse switch off event (from its perspective) as reason to go into suspension mode (similar as closing the laptop lid in battery mode).

What can be done that the computer remains in normal power-on mode in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The phenomena disappeared after a total reboot (shutdown, wait 1 min., boot).
Solved.